# php-imagick + nginx chroot are missing PDF support

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm currently trying to convert an image to PDF in PHP. When running from the commandline the script is working great, but when the exact same code is called from the browser it can't load the PDF module. So its a chroot problem I think?

In phpinfo() the PDF extension isn't showing either in ImageMagick supported formats so thats a red flag.

Error message:
UnableToLoadModule '/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-7.1.1/modules-Q16HDRI/coders/pdf.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1291 in /test.php:8

But when i look inside my chroot folder, this file is present. When converting a JPG to PNG with imagick its working from the browser (and the test script). Its only going wrong with PDF's

Testcode:

```
<?php

$sSourcePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.png';
$sDestinationPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.pdf';
$oImagick = new Imagick($sSourcePath);
$oImagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
$oImagick->writeImage($sDestinationPath);
```

Versions:

```
OS: AlmaLinux 9.2
Nginx: 1.25.2
PHP Version:8.2.9
PHP-Imagick version info:
imagick module version  3.7.0
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel
ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 7.1.1-2 Q16-HDRI x86_64 20952 
Imagick using ImageMagick library version   ImageMagick 7.1.1-15 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21298
```

Things i've tried:

- Other file formats (jpg -> png, png -> jpg), that is working
- I've copied /etc/ and /usr/ into my chroot, didn't made any difference
- Installed Imagick separated with yum install, didn't made any difference
- I've checked the /etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml file. This is inside the policymap:-->
   -->

Changes to this file made no difference, change rights to none, remove lines, it didn't change anything.

- After every change php-fpm and nginx are restarted. So that isn't the problem neither

I'm running out of options to check, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: *"does anyone have any idea?"* Use a pure PHP library such as FPDF?